# Drag and Drop for listview of views

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, drag-and-drop

Hi i am having Listview where each item is having different layout.and i want to perform drag and drop on this listview.i have searched many examples and tried but all works for listview of strings or something like that,none is working on listview of views.finally i decided to go with
 DevBytes: ListView Cell Dragging and Rearranging this one.i implemented dynaliclistview but it is crashing as this also using strings in listview.Following is my listview adapter

```
public class ListViewPagerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ViewPagerAdapter mViewPagerAdapter;
private Context context;
private int selectedIndex;
  FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
  static ViewPager vp;
  LayoutInflater inflater;
  private ArrayList<Integer> mContent;
public ListViewPagerAdapter(Context context,FragmentManager fg) 
{
    super();
    this.context = context;
    mFragmentManager = fg;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return 4;
}

public void setSelectedIndex(int position) {
    selectedIndex = position;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}



@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (convertView == null) {

         inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(position==0)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.titlebar, null);
        }

    }
     if(position==0)
     {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.titlebar, null);
     }
    if(position==1)
    {LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.calendarwidget_layout, null);

    }
     if(position==2)
     {
         LayoutInflater inflater2 = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     convertView = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_list_view, null);
     vp = (ViewPager) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_pager);  


     mViewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(mFragmentManager);
     vp.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);

     }
     if(position==3)
     {
         LayoutInflater inflater2 = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     convertView = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_list_view, null);
     vp = (ViewPager) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_pager);  


     mViewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(mFragmentManager);
     vp.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);
     mViewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


     }


    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

and following is  code for dynamiclisview (same as from mentioned example)

```
public class DynamicListView extends ListView {

private final int SMOOTH_SCROLL_AMOUNT_AT_EDGE = 15;
private final int MOVE_DURATION = 150;
private final int LINE_THICKNESS = 15;

public ArrayList<String> mCheeseList;

private int mLastEventY = -1;

private int mDownY = -1;
private int mDownX = -1;

private int mTotalOffset = 0;

private boolean mCellIsMobile = false;
private boolean mIsMobileScrolling = false;
private int mSmoothScrollAmountAtEdge = 0;

private final int INVALID_ID = -1;
private long mAboveItemId = INVALID_ID;
private long mMobileItemId = INVALID_ID;
private long mBelowItemId = INVALID_ID;

private BitmapDrawable mHoverCell;
private Rect mHoverCellCurrentBounds;
private Rect mHoverCellOriginalBounds;

private final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

private boolean mIsWaitingForScrollFinish = false;
private int mScrollState = OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;

public DynamicListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public DynamicListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

public DynamicListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public void init(Context context) {
    setOnItemLongClickListener(mOnItemLongClickListener);
    setOnScrollListener(mScrollListener);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    mSmoothScrollAmountAtEdge = (int)(SMOOTH_SCROLL_AMOUNT_AT_EDGE / metrics.density);
}

/**
 * Listens for long clicks on any items in the listview. When a cell has
 * been selected, the hover cell is created and set up.
 */
private AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener mOnItemLongClickListener =
        new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
                mTotalOffset = 0;

                int position = pointToPosition(mDownX, mDownY);
                int itemNum = position - getFirstVisiblePosition();

                View selectedView = getChildAt(itemNum);
                mMobileItemId = getAdapter().getItemId(position);
                mHoverCell = getAndAddHoverView(selectedView);
                selectedView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);

                mCellIsMobile = true;

                updateNeighborViewsForID(mMobileItemId);

                return true;
            }
        };

/**
 * Creates the hover cell with the appropriate bitmap and of appropriate
 * size. The hover cell's BitmapDrawable is drawn on top of the bitmap every
 * single time an invalidate call is made.
 */
private BitmapDrawable getAndAddHoverView(View v) {

    int w = v.getWidth();
    int h = v.getHeight();
    int top = v.getTop();
    int left = v.getLeft();

    Bitmap b = getBitmapWithBorder(v);

    BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b);

    mHoverCellOriginalBounds = new Rect(left, top, left + w, top + h);
    mHoverCellCurrentBounds = new Rect(mHoverCellOriginalBounds);

    drawable.setBounds(mHoverCellCurrentBounds);

    return drawable;
}

/** Draws a black border over the screenshot of the view passed in. */
private Bitmap getBitmapWithBorder(View v) {
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(v);
    Canvas can = new Canvas(bitmap);

    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(LINE_THICKNESS);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    can.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    can.drawRect(rect, paint);

    return bitmap;
}

/** Returns a bitmap showing a screenshot of the view passed in. */
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas (bitmap);
    v.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

/**
 * Stores a reference to the views above and below the item currently
 * corresponding to the hover cell. It is important to note that if this
 * item is either at the top or bottom of the list, mAboveItemId or mBelowItemId
 * may be invalid.
 */
private void updateNeighborViewsForID(long itemID) {
    int position = getPositionForID(itemID);
    ListViewPagerAdapter adapter = ((ListViewPagerAdapter)getAdapter());
    mAboveItemId = adapter.getItemId(position - 1);
    mBelowItemId = adapter.getItemId(position + 1);
}

/** Retrieves the view in the list corresponding to itemID */
public View getViewForID (long itemID) {
    int firstVisiblePosition = getFirstVisiblePosition();
    ListViewPagerAdapter adapter = ((ListViewPagerAdapter)getAdapter());
    for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = getChildAt(i);
        int position = firstVisiblePosition + i;
        long id = adapter.getItemId(position);
        if (id == itemID) {
            return v;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/** Retrieves the position in the list corresponding to itemID */
public int getPositionForID (long itemID) {
    View v = getViewForID(itemID);
    if (v == null) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return getPositionForView(v);
    }
}

/**
 *  dispatchDraw gets invoked when all the child views are about to be drawn.
 *  By overriding this method, the hover cell (BitmapDrawable) can be drawn
 *  over the listview's items whenever the listview is redrawn.
 */
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    if (mHoverCell != null) {
        mHoverCell.draw(canvas);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mDownX = (int)event.getX();
            mDownY = (int)event.getY();
            mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mActivePointerId == INVALID_POINTER_ID) {
                break;
            }

            int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);

            mLastEventY = (int) event.getY(pointerIndex);
            int deltaY = mLastEventY - mDownY;

            if (mCellIsMobile) {
                mHoverCellCurrentBounds.offsetTo(mHoverCellOriginalBounds.left,
                        mHoverCellOriginalBounds.top + deltaY + mTotalOffset);
                mHoverCell.setBounds(mHoverCellCurrentBounds);
                invalidate();

                handleCellSwitch();

                mIsMobileScrolling = false;
                handleMobileCellScroll();

                return false;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touchEventsEnded();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            touchEventsCancelled();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            /* If a multitouch event took place and the original touch dictating
             * the movement of the hover cell has ended, then the dragging event
             * ends and the hover cell is animated to its corresponding position
             * in the listview. */
            pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >>
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                touchEventsEnded();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

/**
 * This method determines whether the hover cell has been shifted far enough
 * to invoke a cell swap. If so, then the respective cell swap candidate is
 * determined and the data set is changed. Upon posting a notification of the
 * data set change, a layout is invoked to place the cells in the right place.
 * Using a ViewTreeObserver and a corresponding OnPreDrawListener, we can
 * offset the cell being swapped to where it previously was and then animate it to
 * its new position.
 */
private void handleCellSwitch() {
    final int deltaY = mLastEventY - mDownY;
    int deltaYTotal = mHoverCellOriginalBounds.top + mTotalOffset + deltaY;

    View belowView = getViewForID(mBelowItemId);
    View mobileView = getViewForID(mMobileItemId);
    View aboveView = getViewForID(mAboveItemId);

    boolean isBelow = (belowView != null) && (deltaYTotal > belowView.getTop());
    boolean isAbove = (aboveView != null) && (deltaYTotal < aboveView.getTop());

    if (isBelow || isAbove) {

        final long switchItemID = isBelow ? mBelowItemId : mAboveItemId;
        View switchView = isBelow ? belowView : aboveView;
        final int originalItem = getPositionForView(mobileView);

        if (switchView == null) {
            updateNeighborViewsForID(mMobileItemId);
            return;
        }

        swapElements(mCheeseList, originalItem, getPositionForView(switchView));

        ((BaseAdapter) getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

        mDownY = mLastEventY;

        final int switchViewStartTop = switchView.getTop();

        mobileView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        switchView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        updateNeighborViewsForID(mMobileItemId);

        final ViewTreeObserver observer = getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                observer.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

                View switchView = getViewForID(switchItemID);

                mTotalOffset += deltaY;

                int switchViewNewTop = switchView.getTop();
                int delta = switchViewStartTop - switchViewNewTop;

                switchView.setTranslationY(delta);

                ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(switchView,
                        View.TRANSLATION_Y, 0);
                animator.setDuration(MOVE_DURATION);
                animator.start();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}

private void swapElements(ArrayList arrayList, int indexOne, int indexTwo) {
    Object temp = arrayList.get(indexOne);
    arrayList.set(indexOne, arrayList.get(indexTwo));
    arrayList.set(indexTwo, temp);
}


/**
 * Resets all the appropriate fields to a default state while also animating
 * the hover cell back to its correct location.
 */
private void touchEventsEnded () {
    final View mobileView = getViewForID(mMobileItemId);
    if (mCellIsMobile|| mIsWaitingForScrollFinish) {
        mCellIsMobile = false;
        mIsWaitingForScrollFinish = false;
        mIsMobileScrolling = false;
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

        // If the autoscroller has not completed scrolling, we need to wait for it to
        // finish in order to determine the final location of where the hover cell
        // should be animated to.
        if (mScrollState != OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            mIsWaitingForScrollFinish = true;
            return;
        }

        mHoverCellCurrentBounds.offsetTo(mHoverCellOriginalBounds.left, mobileView.getTop());

        ObjectAnimator hoverViewAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(mHoverCell, "bounds",
                sBoundEvaluator, mHoverCellCurrentBounds);
        hoverViewAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                invalidate();
            }
        });
        hoverViewAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                setEnabled(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mAboveItemId = INVALID_ID;
                mMobileItemId = INVALID_ID;
                mBelowItemId = INVALID_ID;
                mobileView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                mHoverCell = null;
                setEnabled(true);
                invalidate();
            }
        });
        hoverViewAnimator.start();
    } else {
        touchEventsCancelled();
    }
}

/**
 * Resets all the appropriate fields to a default state.
 */
private void touchEventsCancelled () {
    View mobileView = getViewForID(mMobileItemId);
    if (mCellIsMobile) {
        mAboveItemId = INVALID_ID;
        mMobileItemId = INVALID_ID;
        mBelowItemId = INVALID_ID;
        mobileView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        mHoverCell = null;
        invalidate();
    }
    mCellIsMobile = false;
    mIsMobileScrolling = false;
    mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
}

/**
 * This TypeEvaluator is used to animate the BitmapDrawable back to its
 * final location when the user lifts his finger by modifying the
 * BitmapDrawable's bounds.
 */
private final static TypeEvaluator<Rect> sBoundEvaluator = new TypeEvaluator<Rect>() {
    public Rect evaluate(float fraction, Rect startValue, Rect endValue) {
        return new Rect(interpolate(startValue.left, endValue.left, fraction),
                interpolate(startValue.top, endValue.top, fraction),
                interpolate(startValue.right, endValue.right, fraction),
                interpolate(startValue.bottom, endValue.bottom, fraction));
    }

    public int interpolate(int start, int end, float fraction) {
        return (int)(start + fraction * (end - start));
    }
};

/**
 *  Determines whether this listview is in a scrolling state invoked
 *  by the fact that the hover cell is out of the bounds of the listview;
 */
private void handleMobileCellScroll() {
    mIsMobileScrolling = handleMobileCellScroll(mHoverCellCurrentBounds);
}

/**
 * This method is in charge of determining if the hover cell is above
 * or below the bounds of the listview. If so, the listview does an appropriate
 * upward or downward smooth scroll so as to reveal new items.
 */
public boolean handleMobileCellScroll(Rect r) {
    int offset = computeVerticalScrollOffset();
    int height = getHeight();
    int extent = computeVerticalScrollExtent();
    int range = computeVerticalScrollRange();
    int hoverViewTop = r.top;
    int hoverHeight = r.height();

    if (hoverViewTop <= 0 && offset > 0) {
        smoothScrollBy(-mSmoothScrollAmountAtEdge, 0);
        return true;
    }

    if (hoverViewTop + hoverHeight >= height && (offset + extent) < range) {
        smoothScrollBy(mSmoothScrollAmountAtEdge, 0);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public void setCheeseList(ArrayList<String> cheeseList) {
    mCheeseList = cheeseList;
}

/**
 * This scroll listener is added to the listview in order to handle cell swapping
 * when the cell is either at the top or bottom edge of the listview. If the hover
 * cell is at either edge of the listview, the listview will begin scrolling. As
 * scrolling takes place, the listview continuously checks if new cells became visible
 * and determines whether they are potential candidates for a cell swap.
 */
private AbsListView.OnScrollListener mScrollListener = new AbsListView.OnScrollListener () {

    private int mPreviousFirstVisibleItem = -1;
    private int mPreviousVisibleItemCount = -1;
    private int mCurrentFirstVisibleItem;
    private int mCurrentVisibleItemCount;
    private int mCurrentScrollState;

    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                         int totalItemCount) {
        mCurrentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
        mCurrentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;

        mPreviousFirstVisibleItem = (mPreviousFirstVisibleItem == -1) ? mCurrentFirstVisibleItem
                : mPreviousFirstVisibleItem;
        mPreviousVisibleItemCount = (mPreviousVisibleItemCount == -1) ? mCurrentVisibleItemCount
                : mPreviousVisibleItemCount;

        checkAndHandleFirstVisibleCellChange();
        checkAndHandleLastVisibleCellChange();

        mPreviousFirstVisibleItem = mCurrentFirstVisibleItem;
        mPreviousVisibleItemCount = mCurrentVisibleItemCount;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        mCurrentScrollState = scrollState;
        mScrollState = scrollState;
        isScrollCompleted();
    }

    /**
     * This method is in charge of invoking 1 of 2 actions. Firstly, if the listview
     * is in a state of scrolling invoked by the hover cell being outside the bounds
     * of the listview, then this scrolling event is continued. Secondly, if the hover
     * cell has already been released, this invokes the animation for the hover cell
     * to return to its correct position after the listview has entered an idle scroll
     * state.
     */
    private void isScrollCompleted() {
        if (mCurrentVisibleItemCount > 0 && mCurrentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            if (mCellIsMobile && mIsMobileScrolling) {
                handleMobileCellScroll();
            } else if (mIsWaitingForScrollFinish) {
                touchEventsEnded();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the listview scrolled up enough to reveal a new cell at the
     * top of the list. If so, then the appropriate parameters are updated.
     */
    public void checkAndHandleFirstVisibleCellChange() {
        if (mCurrentFirstVisibleItem != mPreviousFirstVisibleItem) {
            if (mCellIsMobile && mMobileItemId != INVALID_ID) {
                updateNeighborViewsForID(mMobileItemId);
                handleCellSwitch();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the listview scrolled down enough to reveal a new cell at the
     * bottom of the list. If so, then the appropriate parameters are updated.
     */
    public void checkAndHandleLastVisibleCellChange() {
        int currentLastVisibleItem = mCurrentFirstVisibleItem + mCurrentVisibleItemCount;
        int previousLastVisibleItem = mPreviousFirstVisibleItem + mPreviousVisibleItemCount;
        if (currentLastVisibleItem != previousLastVisibleItem) {
            if (mCellIsMobile && mMobileItemId != INVALID_ID) {
                updateNeighborViewsForID(mMobileItemId);
                handleCellSwitch();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

}

And following is list.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.bin.widget.DynamicListView
    android:id="@+id/campaignListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#0000"
     >
</com.bin.widget.DynamicListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

please help me out...thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HI I finally solved this problem myself,above code works by making few changes in adapter class of listview.In adapter's public long getItemId(int position) make necessary changes so that it will give you id of passed positions view.Dont just return position. Also,in dynamicListview class after swapping position refresh of listview is being done so in listadapter's getview() method,we need to make changes accordingly.
That's it,then it works like charm.Hope this helps somebody else too.

Comment: Hi, can you please put your answer here or edit your question with the corrected code? I need it because I've been searching for quite long time and haven't found any working example. Thank you