# Android List View with BaseAdapter Drag and Drop sort

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, drag-and-drop

I have a list of records in a listview that I want the user to be able to re-sort using a drag and drop method. **I am using BaseAdapter for that listview.** 
I have not found a tutorial for it. Can anyone point me to some code for doing this?

Comment: Yes, I want it by Drag and Drop rearrangement.

Comment: Check [DevBytes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BZIvjMgH-Q) tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arraylist of your Model.

```
private ArrayList<YourModel> albumList = new ArrayList<YourModel>();
//add item in your list.

DragSortListView listView = (DragSortListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_test);

ReorderAlbumAdapter adapter = new ReorderAlbumAdapter(this, albumList);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setDropListener(onDrop);
listView.setRemoveListener(onRemove);

private DragSortListView.DropListener onDrop = new DragSortListView.DropListener() {
    @Override
    public void drop(int from, int to) {
        if (from != to) {
            AlbumModel item = adapter.getItem(from);
            adapter.remove(item);
            adapter.insert(item, to);
        }
    }
};



private DragSortListView.RemoveListener onRemove = new DragSortListView.RemoveListener() {
    @Override
    public void remove(int which) {
        adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(which));
    }
};
```

XML for listview is:

```
<com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            dslv:collapsed_height="2dp"
            dslv:drag_enabled="true"
            dslv:drag_handle_id="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            dslv:drag_scroll_start="0.33"
            dslv:drag_start_mode="onMove"
            dslv:float_alpha="0.6"
            dslv:max_drag_scroll_speed="0.5"
            dslv:remove_enabled="true"
            dslv:remove_mode="flingRemove"
            dslv:slide_shuffle_speed="0.3"
            dslv:sort_enabled="true"
            dslv:track_drag_sort="false"
            dslv:use_default_controller="true" />
```

You should use arrayadapter for your model. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Am I right in thinking the com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView class is https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview ? No longer maintained. :-(

Comment: Yes, the library is no longer maintained and everyone is answering with this library only.

Comment: i am using my base adapter and there is no such a method remove and insert so how can i use this?

Answer (score 2):

There are working set of codes for **Drag-and-Drop using ListView** by a starting developer in Google team @ [ListViewDraggingAnimation zip](http://developer.android.com/shareables/devbytes/ListViewDraggingAnimation.zip). There is a video explaining the internal code @ [ListView Cell Dragging and Rearranging](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BZIvjMgH-Q). You don't have to understand the code in DynamicListView.

Sample code to start:

```
StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.text_view, mCheeseList);
DynamicListView listView = (DynamicListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

listView.setCheeseList(mCheeseList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Notes:

1. For calling `StableArrayAdapter` constructor using "**this**" object works in an Activity. If on Fragment subclass, use **getContext**() or similar.
2. ArrayList `mCheeseList` is an example. Use another list that is appropriate for your code. Personally I would like to use my own custom class instead of the simple ArrayList
3. Again if you're using Fragment like me, use **view.findViewById** instead of just `findViewById` method call.
4. Finally, maybe most important is the sample uses the popular ArrayAdapter subclass, **StableArrayAdapter**. This could be easily changed to using BaseAdapter subclass instead (fitting your code). You'll have to pass the data to StableArrayAdapter somehow, and that's the main thing. Interestingly, the only code that uses **ArrayAdapter** in StableArrayAdapter class is the `getItem` method call.
5. I found an interesting sample of **BaseAdapter** subclass code that looks good @ Stackoverflow [Drag and Drop for listview of views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451731/drag-and-drop-for-listview-of-views). This probably deserves more attention.

Personally this is my first time implementing Drag-and-Drop function. The code offers a rather simple example with one TextView. I need to customize it using 3 UI elements in my layout instead of just one. I think I can customize Google's sample code to my own needs, a common goal.

I hope this post and my notes will help others since Drag-and-Drop functionality has not been developed into the Android SDK, and sorely needs one.
Good luck and have fun...Tommy Kwee

Comment: Kudos for not giving that outdated library reference in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the link for your listview that provides DragDrop functionality.Check [This link](https://github.com/terlici/DragNDropList)

replace your listview with

```
<com.terlici.dragndroplist.DragNDropListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

in your activity class

```
DragNDropListView list = (DragNDropListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

DragNDropCursorAdapter adapter = new DragNDropCursorAdapter(context,
                       R.layout.row,
                       cursor,
                       new String[]{"text"},
                       new int[]{R.id.text},
                       R.id.handler);

list.setDragNDropAdapter(adapter);
```

it also provides drag drop interface,exactly what you want.

Comment: It is using DragNDropCursorAdapter, but I need it with baseAdapter.

Comment: DragNDropCusorAdapter is a Custom class which extends ListAdapter.

Comment: I want it with baseAdapter, as I have already implemented all other functinalities with it.

Answer (score -1):

```
listView.setDropListener(onDrop);
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
private DragSortListView.DropListener onDrop = new DragSortListView.DropListener() {
    @Override
    public void drop(int from, int to) {

        if (from != to) {
            // DragSortListView list = listView;
            YourModel item = adapter.getItem(from);
            adapter.remove(item);
            adapter.insert(item, to)
    }
};
```

Add below methods in baseadapter

```
public void remove(YourModel item) {
    aryList.remove(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void insert(YourModel item, int position) {
    aryList.add(position, item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In Xml :

```
<com.mobeta.android.dslv.DragSortListView
    android:id="@+id/lstvw"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    dslv:collapsed_height="1px"
    dslv:drag_enabled="true"
    dslv:drag_handle_id="@+id/drag_handle1"
    dslv:drag_scroll_start="0.33"
    dslv:drag_start_mode="onDown"
    dslv:float_alpha="0.6"
    dslv:remove_enabled="false"
    dslv:slide_shuffle_speed="0.3" />
```